# Use Microsoft AntiVirus API for File Upload Scanning

Tags: antivirus

Has anyone here used Microsoft Anti-Virus API to scan file uploads using any anti-virus ? What is your experience. I want to use mcafee, trend or other well known AV to be called programatically.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Microsoft AntiVirus API is not suitable for scanning uploaded files. From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537371(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537371%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The Antivirus API enables software
>   vendors to develop applications that
>   **scan Microsoft Office 2000 documents
>   before opening them**. **The API also
>   supports scanning Microsoft Internet
>   Explorer 5 code downloads, such as
>   Microsoft ActiveX Controls or
>   installs. However, be aware that the
>   Windows Internet Explorer scanning
>   support applies only to automatic code
>   downloads and not to file downloads or
>   HTML documents**. The primary purpose of
>   this API is to give an independent
>   software vendor (ISV) the ability to
>   design and implement scanning software
>   that can be used by all applications.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You should either invest money into a malware filtering appliance (using something like ICAP or a proprietary protocol) that will scan all inbound traffic for virus/malware even before it hits your app. Here are some examples:

http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/spam_overview.php

Another route is to do API level integration with a SaaS provider such as [scanii.com](http://scanii.com)